# How can I insert a thin space (\,) in a listing?

Tags: spacing, listings

Is it possible to create small space in listing? I tried / and \, but it doesn't work in listing environment

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Inicializace ELM327.}, label={lst:initELM},captionpos=b]
send_data("A\,T\/Z"); %I need mini space between letters.
sleep(2000);
send_data("ATE0");
...
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `listings` treats pretty much all characters *verbatim*. The only way of using a macro such as `\,` inside a listing is to invoke that macro within an *escape to LaTeX*; look up the `escapechar` key (or `escapeinside` ) key in the `listings` manual (subsection 4.14).

Comment: This can be done, yes, if you misuse `escapeinside` or thelike, see the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176736/4736). *But don't do this*, because people happily will try to copy your code out of the document to test or play around with it and the compilation will fail because there suddenly are spaces were no spaces are supposed to be!

Comment: Anyway, inserting a thinspace into a listing feels wrong to me, especially if the listing in question is supposed to only contain ASCII characters. That's just going to confuse your readers who will likely be left wondering: *Is there a space or not?*

Comment: It was because letters were fused.

Comment: @SpeedEX505 You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us what you mean by "fused".

Comment: @Jubobs One letter covers another

Comment: @SpeedEX505.  Which letters? What font? Image please & code please. Maybe you could try a different font, because this doesn't usually happen with the monospaced fonts preferred for listings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much all characters are printed *verbatim* in an `lstlisting` environment. The only way of using a macro such as `\,` inside a listing is to invoke that macro within an *escape to LaTeX*; look up the `escapechar` key (or `escapeinside`) key in the `listings` manual (subsection 4.14).

However, introducing thin spaces in that fashion is very ad-hoc and awkward. If all you want is to improve the spacing between letters in your listings, you should just set

```
columns=fullflexible
```

More details are given in subsection `2.10` of the `listings` manual. See below for a comparison of what that option does.

Side note: I also recommend you use some monospaced font for your listings (e.g. `basicstyle=\ttfamily`).

### Without `columns=fullflexible`

[image]

### With `columns=fullflexible`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Inicializace ELM327.}, label={lst:initELM},captionpos=b]
send_data("ATZ"); %I need mini space between letters.
sleep(2000);
send_data("ATE0");
...
...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```