# Different colours for each argument and value in listings

Tags: macros, listings, code

[This recent question (Print blue brackets in one language and black in another)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176676/print-blue-brackets-in-one-language-and-black-in-another) made me come up with (up to) two more questions regarding the `listings` package:

1. Is there an option similar to `opstyle` that only affects **one** argument (using `"`, `,` or `;` as first delimiter and `=` as a second) and **one** value belonging to that argument? (using `=` as first delimiter and `"`, `,` or `;` as second)?
2. Is it possible to adjust the used colour in the middle of the `listings` environment, without it showing up as comment or line, etc.? These solutions all define colours outside the actual environment.

Neither the [`listings` manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), nor the [WikiBooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) give conclusive answers (and also fail mentioning macros including `\lst@thestyle` I might add), so I've looked at `listings.sty`, unsurprisingly to no avail, partially because the `.sty`-file has absolutely no remarks on any line for explanation.

For your convenience, I've included the MWE of the `opstyle` example and picture from the thread earlier mentioned. In my case I'd like to for instance colour the part of `string: ()` orange, but the `{}><;&` part red.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\opstyle{\color{red}} % <--- customise operator style here

\makeatletter

\lstset
{%
  language=C++,
  alsoletter=0123456789,% to prevent \opstyle from being applied to digits
}

% Hook into listings
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\ProcessOther@silmeth}

% helper macro
\newcommand\ProcessOther@silmeth
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\opstyle}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int i = 0;
if(i > 1) && (1/2 < 2) {

    // one-line comment ()={}><;&

    printf("string: ()={}><;&");

    /*
      block comment ()={}><&;
    */
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: opstyle example]

Comment: `\lst@thestyle` is an internal macro. The `listings` user's guide doesn't mention it, because the "average user" is not supposed to know about it. Besides, the `.sty` is meant not to contain any comments on the implementation; the `.sty` is generated from the [`.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx) (which stands for "Documented laTeX"); that's where you'll find all the comments.

Comment: You comment that the `.sty`  has no comments: like most latex packages it is distributed using `dcostrip` which removes all the comments, the original source is a full latex document, which you probably have as `texmf-dist/source/latex/listings/listings.dtx` but which you can view as pdf wth `texdoc listings`  It says amongst other things: `%       If you want a special printing style, modify |\lst@thestyle|.`

Comment: The short answer to your first question is: **no**, that's not possible. The long answer is: **maybe**, but only with tremendous modifications of the way `listings` handles delimiters. I'm not sure I understand your second question.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81646/how-can-i-highlight-text-before-a-character-with-listing

Comment: @Jubobs The second question is about a `\textcolor{<color>}{<argument>}` equivalent (or a macro thereof) in the `listings` environments (which will usually be read verbatim).

Comment: @1010011010 See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175374/how-can-i-insert-a-thin-space-in-a-listing#comment405781_175374